# div showing empty contents

Tags: html, laravel

I have this div:

```
<div id="rightside"><br>
        @yield('drop')
    </div><br>
```

and this section:

```
@extends('layouts.drop')

@section('drop')
<html>

<div class="form-group">
        <p id="select">Please make selection for {{ $code }}</p>
       <select class="form-control" name="item_id" style="width: 400px">
        @foreach($items as $item)
          <option value="{{ $item->data }}">{{ $item->data }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
</div>
</html>
@stop
```

When I display the layout for this, nothing shows up in the div. Nothing, nada.
I use the div previously in another layout and it displays with no problem. Three hours searching and cannot find solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you passing `$items` to the view?

Comment: Yes, I tested it by just loading the $item object in a page and it worked fine.

Comment: `<?php var_dump($items); ?>` right before your foreach to make sure you're getting your array at least to the foreach.

Comment: OK, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the data.

Comment: You said in the question nothing was showing, but is `Please make selection for {{ $code }}` displaying correctly?

Comment: The page is blank. Nothing shows

Comment: Are you sure it's getting into the `drop` section at all? Sounds like it's not rendering.

Comment: I can't understand it. Prior to this page I have a previous page that does the exact same thing but with a php table and it works perfectly.

Comment: Is that div in the `layouts.drop` file?

Comment: Yes. I even tried changing all the file names but that did not work. I changed them back.

Comment: I'll try again tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've found the problem. I was using the child view improperly. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it. It did help me find the problem.